# The 'poster' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I keep getting this error every time I try to load my home page. This is the error I'm getting from chrome debugger:

```
The 'poster' attribute has no file associated with it.
  
 1  <!DOCTYPE html>
    2   <html lang="en">
    3   <head>
    4       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    5       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    6       <title>Episode One</title>
    7       {% load static %}
    8       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    9       <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    10  </head>
    11  <body>

During handling of the above exception ('ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Pilot(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    count = models.IntegerField()
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    script = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="scripts")
    poster = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="posters")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('script_app.urls')),
] 

if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

I can't figure out what is tripping up. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
poster = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='default.png', upload_to="posters")
```

you are being shown error as everytime jinja loop tries to parse the image, if they find nothing they show error.to prevent this,you either **upload all images** or set a **default.png** in your **posters** folder,and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried what you recommended but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: hello,are you there?

Comment: Yes, how are you?

Answer (score 0):

In Html code the {%load static%} is come always on top and you has put it in middle its wrong to load static files.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    2   <html lang="en">
    3   <head>
    4       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    5       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    6       <title>Episode One</title>
    8       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    9       <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    10  </head>
    11  <body>
```

And in setting.py try this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Try what i has done above. It will help you.

Comment: Hey Rayyan, I did the recommended changes but now I've created another error in my terminal:

Comment: File "/Users/tonyhall/Documents/projects/scripts/scripts/urls.py", line 30, in <module>
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  File "/Users/tonyhall/Documents/python_stack/my_environment/py3Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/urls/static.py", line 22, in static
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted

Comment: change your URL.py like i did : urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)